# Why do I need to specify window variable scope in backbone route filter?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm using the backbone route filter, https://github.com/fantactuka/backbone-route-filter, in my backbone.js app. It's a one page app, so I was trying to record pageviews using a KissMetrics event tracking snippet. Here is the code:

```
before: {
    '*any': function(fragment, args) {

    }
  },

  after: {
    '*any': function(fragment) {

      var _kmq = window._kmq || [];
      _kmq.push(['record', 'Viewed ' + fragment]);
    }
  },
```

The question is, the event wasn't tracking unless I specified the 'window' scope of the _kmq variable. Why? In my index.html, or the one page with all my js code, I have:

```
var _kmq = _kmq || [];
```

which I thought would make the variable at the global level automatically...this is the link to a typical implementation: http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/javascript/index.html In every case I've seen prior the common api method worked, without setting the scope to window: http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/javascript/javascript-specific/index.html

Why did I need to specify 'window._kmq' rather than just '_kmq'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue of local versus global scoping (see [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for some examples of this).

Since you're including the Kiss Metrics Javascript on the page, it will be looking in the global (that is `window._kmq`) variable for event updates. To make sure you are pushing your event into that globally accessible variable, you need to specify that it lives in the global context (ie, `window._kmq`) versus a local context (ie, `_kmq`).

In your Javascript code that lives directly on the page, the default scope is inside `window`, so `var _kmq = ...` is the same as `window._kmq = ...`.

In your Backbone router, this isn't the case: the scope inside there is isolated (that is, if you set `var _kmq = ...` inside the router, it isn't accessible anywhere except in that same block of code).

Comment: What is the scope of the backbone router?

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! I was confused because when I include `_kmq` in a _view_, the event passes fine. So the scope of the view is at window and that of the router is not?

Comment: I'd need to see more code, but I'd guess that you're *referencing* `_kmq` which is defaulting to the global scope. When you *set* `var _kmq` inside the method (like you were doing) it is set in the local scope only.